# How do I draw a circle at every point in a gnuplot splot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a set of 3d points stored in a file, as in the standard

```
set style data lines
splot 'data.dat'
```

Except I want to draw a circle in the x-y plane along with every point drawn, so that what will be rendered in the end will be a curving tube with the central line on the inside.

I've been able to draw individual circles using parameters, but I'm not sure how you'd do what I've described here.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want circles, the following might be a solution which comes to my mind. But maybe you actually want a surface plotted? For this there might be other solutions.

**Code:**

```
### circles along datapoints
reset session

# create some 3D test data
set samples 50
set table $Data
    plot [0:1.5] '+' u (cos(2*pi*$1)):(sin(2*pi*$1)):($1*10) w table
unset table

# define the circle
Radius = 0.1
set samples 24
set table $Circle
    plot [0:1] '+' u (cos(2*pi*$1)):(sin(2*pi*$1)) w table
unset table

Offset(i,axis) = real(word($Data[i],axis))

set view 65,124
splot $Data u 1:2:3 w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "red", \
      for [i=1:|$Data|] $Circle u ($1+Offset(i,1)):($2+Offset(i,2)):(Offset(i,3)) w l notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here is a slightly modified version (maybe there is a simpler way to achieve it) where you create a datablock `$Tube` which can be plotted with surfaces. The circles are still parallel to the xy-plane. Although, my suspicion is that you actually might wanted to have the circles orthogonal to the direction of the input data path.

**Code:**

```
### circle surface along datapoints
reset session

# create some test data
set samples 50
set table $Data
    plot [0:1.5] '+' u (cos(2*pi*$1)):(sin(2*pi*$1)):($1*10) w table
unset table

# define the circle
Radius = 0.1
set samples 24
set table $Circle
    plot [0:1] '+' u (cos(2*pi*$1)):(sin(2*pi*$1)) w table
unset table

D(i,axis) = real(word($Data[i],axis))
C(i,axis) = real(word($Circle[i],axis))

# generate "tube" datapoints
set print $Tube
do for [i=1:|$Circle|] {
    do for [j=1:|$Data|] {
        print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f", C(i,1)+D(j,1), C(i,2)+D(j,2), D(j,3))
    }
    print ""  # empty line
}
set print
set pm3d depthorder noborder
set pm3d lighting specular 0.5

set view 65,124
splot $Data u 1:2:3 w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "red", \
      $Tube u 1:2:3 w pm3d notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think you're right-  looking at how the graph has turned out, I would probably be best served by a surface instead.

Comment: well, that's what you asked for ;-). I added some more code for plotting a surface.

Comment: I should have asked which question to ask!  Thanks for the extra code, looks great!